# Using Azure Function Deployment Slots with EventHub

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure function app that processes data from an EventHub. My current CI/CD process uses deployment slots to deploy:

1. Deploy function to staging slot
2. Validate staging slot with a smoke test
3. Swap staging with production

The CI/CD flow itself is working without issue. However, during the time my staging slot is active, I'm essentially double-processing messages off the EventHub as there are two active function apps.

What is the best practice way to handle CI/CD for integration apps like this? Is there a way to pin events to a certain slot with EventHub in the function binding? Perhaps it's unavoidable and doubling-down on idempotentency is the solution?

Comment: This is an interesting question since Event Hubs will allow only one active deployment against a certain consumer group. I wonder if you are deploying both production and staging targeting the same EH consumer group.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually specifying the consumer group in the function so the staging slot should be using the same as production. It seems strange to make a consumer group for staging, especially given that it would double my cost. Maybe the way I'm using the staging slot as a primer into prod is misguided?

Comment: Since these are different slots for the same deployment, I would expect service to trigger only production slot function and avoid duplicates. Maybe someone from Functions can help to correct my understanding.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca - do you have anyone from that team you could mention for assistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage slot sticky app settings to define which consumer group to use, which would get applied to during [swap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#swap-operations).

Do make sure you are using setting the consumer group property to an app setting reference.

With this approach, you could have a separate consumer group for the smoke test and on swap, the production consumer group would be used.

Comment: The "Deployment slot setting" option was exactly what I needed here. Thank you!